# Fill different color in intersection 2,3... circle on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math

I've working with google map api and I'm facing the problem:

1. Now on the map screen, draw one circle center point A, the radius R1
2. draw another circle at B, the radius R2
3. I want to fill 3 different colors;

   - 1 for circle 1,
   - 1 for circle 2,
   - And 1 for the intersection between two circles (part of the circle 1 and 2)(Not color mixing between 2 circle)
     or find the polygon of this intersection ?

Anyone have experience/worked with this issue Please advice me, or suggest third party or another technical can resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use google.maps.Circles to color the intersection between two circles.  You need to use three separate google.maps.Polygon objects and color them independently

Comment: You don't understand my question?

Comment: I know that I can use Circles of google map to draw 2 circle with different color and with opacity about 0.5. So now the intersection will be mixing color. But I want to find another technical or third party???

Comment: I've asked Google support for this issue, and the answer is: Google doesn't support this function to detect intersection between two circles. So you should use the solution.

"Circles of google map to draw 2 circle with different color and with opacity about 0.5. So now the intersection will be mixing color"